# How to upload an image with the wordpress api in Python?

Tags: python, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

I hope your are fine.

I would like to upload an image in my wordpress library from my computer.
I wrote few lines in Python that use Wordpress API.

It is working when I use 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
However, the content added is not an image.

When I change it with 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' I get an error message which says:
Error 403 please forward this error screen to the site owner

What should I do, contact my web hosting company ?

Thank you all for you help

Here is my code:

```
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
import requests
import base64
import json
import time
import os


user = "user"
password = "pass"

url = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2"
data_string = user + ':' + password

token = base64.b64encode(data_string.encode())

# headers={'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'), 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg','Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=%s'% "test.jpg"}
headers={'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'), 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=%s'% "test.jpg"}



video = {
    "title": "test",
    "description": "description",
    "media-type": "image",
}

r = requests.post(url + "/media", headers=headers, json=video)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code

```
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
import requests
import base64
import json
import time
import os


user = "user"
password = "pass"

url = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2"
data_string = user + ':' + password

token = base64.b64encode(data_string.encode())

headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}


image = {
    "file": open("toto.png", "rb"),
    "caption": "caption",
    "description": "description",
}

r = requests.post(url + "/media", headers=headers, files=image)
print(r.text)
print(r)
```